# Python and matplotlib - Error making a chaos game

Tags: python, matplotlib

I´m trying to make a chaos game using python. What happens is that when I run it 100 times (just to test) it makes me 2 triangles with random points. It should give me 103 points...

What can be the problem? I am tired of reading and reading again but still I cannot find the error. Thanks for any help! Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import math
import random
t=0
pontos = [[0, 0],[5,math.sqrt(75)],[10, 0]]
plt.plot([0, 5, 10], [ 0, math.sqrt(75), 0], "ro")
x = random.randint(0, 100)
y = random.randint(0, 100)
while t < 100:
   rv=random.choice(pontos)
   rvx=rv[0]
   rvy=rv[1]
   medx=(rvx+x)/2
   medy=(rvy+y)/2
   plt.plot([medx], [medy], "ro")
   t = t+1
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your while loop, `rv` is always one of three possible values (the elements of `pontos`). The points that get plotted in the loop are based on that and a random `x` and `y` value. But `x` and `y` are only set once, outside the loop, so they're constant. Hence your plot will always have the same 6 points: the 3 from the plot command outside the loop, and the ones from `pontos` with the random constant values added.

If you want the triangles to be random, the assignment of `x` and `y` needs to be moved inside the loop.